# Add Animation effect on Morris Chart

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, morris.js

I Have created a chart By using Morris JS. For now the Chart Simply Loads on the screen without any effect. I want to make the chart little more interesting by adding Animation effect to it.

Here is my Script :

```
<script>
 Morris.Area({
  element: 'chart',
  // json_encode returns JSON representation of a value
  data: <?php echo json_encode($json_data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)?>,
  xkey: 'label',
  ykeys: ['value'],
  // Set to false to skip time/date parsing for X values, instead treating 
 them as an equally-spaced series.
  parseTime:false,
  labels: ['<b>Registered Users</b>'],
   pointFillColors: ['#6789ab'],
 pointStrokeColors: ['#112233'],
 lineColors: ['#a9b4d6'],
  resize: true
  });
</script>
```

I Know it will done by the Help of css but I don't know How should I persue the procedure.

The Div box I am using is :

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

But I want only the chart to show the Animation effect

Comment: Can you create a working example here or in [CodeSandbox](http://codesandbox.io/)?

Answer (score 0):

I explain here how to make animation effect with Morris Chart: [how to animate morris bar chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441502/how-to-animate-morris-bar-chart)

This requires several changes. The good news is that you can use my fork that includes these changes :) : https://pierresh.github.io/morris.js/